# How can I get the longest list in Julia dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Give a dataframe like this :

```
dataframe = DataFrame(col1 = rand(3), 
                      col2 = [['a'],['a','b','c'],['a','c']])
```

How can I get the longest list in `col2`?

I tried with :

```
dataframe[partialsortperm(dataframe.col2, 1, rev=true), :]
```

but It returns `['a','c']` instead of `['a','b','c]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] Actually, you want `argmax`:

```
julia> argmax(length, dataframe.col2)
3-element Vector{Char}:
 'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'b': ASCII/Unicode U+0062 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'c': ASCII/Unicode U+0063 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

---

[pre-EDIT answer below:]

I think you want to use `findmax`:

```
julia> findmax(length, dataframe.col2) # returns (max length, index)
(3, 2)

julia> dataframe.col2[findmax(length, dataframe.col2)[2]]
3-element Vector{Char}:
 'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'b': ASCII/Unicode U+0062 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'c': ASCII/Unicode U+0063 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

Comment: Edited my answer. You actually want to use `argmax`!